# Create a new map in groovy by taking the values of one map and making it keys of another map

Tags: groovy, hashmap

I have two map in the following way

```
def map1 = ['a':1,'b':2]
def map2 = ['a':345,'c':10,'b':1]
```

I would like to create a result map which would look basically look to match the keys of the two maps and would make the value of map1 as the key and value of map2 as the value itself. The output would look like this:

```
 map3=[1:345,2:1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with a simple loop:

```
map3 = map1.collectEntries { key, val -> [(val): map2[key]] }
```

Comment: i'd use `collectEntries` instead: `map1.collectEntries{ k,v -> [v, map2[k]] }`

Comment: `collectEntries` is a better solution imho, as you don't need to create an empty map then mutate it in a loop which feels a bit dirty this day and age...

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for pointing that out, it's definitely a better choice. Was too tired when I used `each`.